# 404 error when downloading file from webserver from "itself"

Tags: apache-httpd

I need to, somehow, allow my server to download files from itself. I have to use `wget` from `example.com` on file `example.com/script.json`, but when I try that, I am getting 404 error

```
Resolving https://example.com (example.com )... 1.2.3.4
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|1.2.3.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-12-04 11:10:50 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

File is in directory `/home/site.com/apps/frontend/public`

Do I somehow setup localhost for this domain? I feel like I do, but was not able to figure out how.

Comment: just curious, why would you need that?

Comment: Edit question to tell us. Is this on a home system. What is the output of `ip addr`. If you go to what's my IP, do you get the address in the error message.

Comment: @schaiba because they do. Maybe to test the site (though they will latter need to test from external system).

Comment: @schaiba its for testing sake on development site.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor .. not sure how will ip actually solve this problem? I am thinking its Apache issue?

Comment: Anyway here is my ip a output @ctrl-alt-delor

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:1f:ff:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.2.3.4/25 brd 2.4.8.10 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:1ab0:7e1f:1:5054:ff:fe1f:fff7/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591949sec preferred_lft 604749sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe1f:fff7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: Edit question to tell us. Is this on a home system. What is the output of ip addr. If you go to what's my IP, do you get the address in the error message.

Comment: I thing your command is `wget -O- 'https://example.com/script.json'`. To which directory does the virtual host configuration point to, e.g. `/var/www/html/example.com`, and what is the entire path of the file? It should be under this directory, e.g. `/var/www/html/example.com/script.json`.

Comment: Firstly try to download file from ip address. May be you have some problem with dns.

Comment: @rexkogitans edited question where is file stored. Its root directory of the apache vhost

Comment: Is `/home/site.com/apps/frontend/public` the directory the vhost points to, and is the user `www-data` (this is the user apache runs as) allowed to access the directory?

Comment: It has the proper user and group. It is with no problems accesible via browser, I just cant use WGET on it localy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `ServerAlias localhost`, after adding this to configuration I was able to use wget `https://localhost/file.json` and it worked.